AC car pipe freezes after ~20min turned on
My AC stops cooling after ~20 minutes of work. I open the hood and I see this:

It completely freezes. The AC works great while it does.
What could be the problem?
Thanks

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! My first inclination is, your charge may be low, but I wouldn't know for sure.

Is that the high or low pressure pipe?

Frankly, I'm not sure. What do you have in mind?
